# Установить значение disabled="disabled"  в select

Tags: javascript

Отключение полей на сайте происходит стилями конкретно параметром disabled="disabled", если в конце написать просто disabled ничего не произойдет

```
  <select id="otdelenie" class="b-core-ui-select__select" name="otdelenie"  disabled="disabled">
  <option>Выбрать отделение почты</option>
  </select>
```

Вопрос как с помощью JS установить в элемент значение disabled="disabled" в селект.

ТО что сейчас есть, работает, но на чистой форме без css

```
function Gorod_dis() {
    document.getElementById('gorod').disabled = true;
  }

function Gorod_en() {
    document.getElementById('gorod').disabled = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вопрос правильно понял...

disabled="disabled" - это атрибут тега, а не стиль.

Вот пример установки атрибута определенному тегу.

```
document.getElementById('otdelenie').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
```